# Does the existence of uncomputable functions imply that a theory is incomplete?

Tags: computability, incompleteness

For example Kolmogorov complexity is uncomputable and Chaitin used that fact to prove incompleteness.

If this is not the case, can you give me a counter example?

Set of axioms is countable.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not quite correct.

One crucial point is that there be a *definable* non-computable function. For instance, Presburger Arithmetic is complete and recursive; the point is that no interesting functions are definable in its language. By contrast, in Chaitin's proof a crucial point is that Kolmogorov complexity *is* definable in PA.

Another crucial point is that you also need to take into account the complexity of the theory. For instance, the full first-order theory of arithmetic, $Th(\mathbb{N})$, is complete by definition, even though plenty of noncomputable functions are definable in arithmetic. The point is that every function definable in the language of arithmetic is recursive *relative to $Th(\mathbb{N})$.*

Here's one correct way to say what you're getting at:

> Suppose $T$ is a theory in some language $L$, and $T$ is satisfied by an $L$-structure $\mathcal{N}$ whose underlying set is $\mathbb{N}$, and the elements of this underlying set are *effecitvely definable* in the sense that there is a recursive map $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that $g(i)$ is (the Godel number of) a formula defining $i$ in $\mathcal{N}$. Then if $f$ is a function definable in $L$, whose interpretation in $\mathcal{N}$ (viewed as a function on $\mathbb{N}$) is not recursive relative to $T$, then $T$ is incomplete.

There are many other ways to formalize this. For instance, we might not want to assume much about the "truth" of $T$ - this is where *representability*, as opposed to mere definability, comes into play.